# Acordeon menu like "google current" app ?

Tags: android, menu

I was wondering, has anyone done a menu like google currents app?

Like this one:
https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-2RaScN7VmVY/UQIdAhkFC6I/AAAAAAAADKQ/1ogpA87bE3g/s2048/Photo%25252025%252520janv.%2525202013%25252009%25253A27.jpg

I've been all week searching for a collapsable menu ( preferibly in a fragment so i can use it on a master-detail flow ) and i havent found anything!

I've also tried adapting expandableList menues but failed to do so ( as 100% of demos are in activities and not in fragments )

Any help would be aprecciated, thanks!

Comment: do you mean NavigationDrawer?  http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html

Comment: Go to [this](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidActionBar/article.html#actionbar_navigation_drawer) link.

Comment: Nope, i meant the ''acordeon'' part of the menu, so i can click an option and it shows me more options related ( Eg: I click ''Clothes'' and is now shows me ''shirts'' and things like that ) The navigation drawer in android, as far as i understand, doesnt have any implementation for multi level menues, and as im kinda new to this, i was wondering if anybody had tried doing that